# Call Arbitrary Constructor With Arbitrary Arguments

Tags: php, function

Given the name of the class as $class, and the arguments to pass to the constructor an an array $args, can I actually create a new instance of $class?

It's possible using else-if chains (up to the maximum number of arguments you want to support) and using eval, but neither of those are clean. I'm looking for something that is only one or two lines, ideally.

Comment: Jack: I agree that it is. On the other hand, this question has a more detailed answer that that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by using [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). The method you're looking for specifically is [newInstanceArgs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php)

```
$class = 'YourClass';
$args = array ('a', 'b');

$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($class); 
$classInstance = $reflection->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php) to do this

```
$myClass = "NameOfClass"; //Name of class as string 
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($myClass); 
$params = array(1,2); //it can be a dynamic array of parameters
$myObject = $reflection->newInstanceArgs($params);
```

Comment: This doesn't call the constructor with arbitrary arguments -- it calls it with none.

Comment: oh. corrected the answer to contain dynamic params for class constructor

Comment: This doesn't make sense..

Comment: why not? what is the problem with it?

Comment: After you've fixed it, it's okay.

Comment: Yeha, now it's my answer. :D

Comment: :-) yeah I messed it up at first with my previous answer.

Comment: @Sherlock yes and may be the only possible answer :-)